# How to get complete month name from DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

What is the proper way to get the complete name of month of a `DateTime` object?
e.g. `January`, `December`.

I am currently using:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMMMMMMMMMMM");
```

I know it's not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 347):

Use [the "MMMM" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MMMM_Specifier):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
```

Comment: If it's only the month you're interested in then DateTime.Today instead of DateTime.Now is a further simplification. No useless time portion and a bit faster.

Comment: Surprisingly I'm getting the very text "MMMM"

Comment: DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("MMMM");  will give you "MMMM".   Is that what you did?

Comment: DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("MMMM") resulted in MMMM string.. not useful

Comment: Drop the 'Month' portion from your code. Should be: DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");

Answer (score 105):

You can do as [mservidio suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765463), or even better, keep track of your culture using this overload:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That's neat, I need to look into this culture stuff.

Comment: If it's only the month you're interested in then DateTime.Today instead of DateTime.Now is a further simplification. No useless time portion and a bit faster.

Answer (score 43):

If you want the current month you can use
`DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")` to get the full month or `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM")` to get an abbreviated month.

If you have some other date that you want to get the month string for, after it is loaded into a DateTime object, you can use the same functions off of that object:
`dt.ToString("MMMM")` to get the full month or `dt.ToString("MMM")` to get an abbreviated month.

Reference:
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Alternatively, if you need culture specific month names, then you could try these:
[DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname.aspx)
[DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx)

Comment: +1 for mentioning how to do it from a `DateTime` that is NOT `DateTime.Now`.  I had thought it was `string mon = myDate.Month.ToString("MMM")` when I was sadly let down by it spitting "MMM" into my string variable.  Glad you took the effort to show how to use `.ToString("MMM")` on the date, itself, to get the month, when it's not `DateTime.Now`. And how you explained the difference between `MMM` and `MMMM`.  Best answer on this page.  Kudos.

Comment: If it's only the month you're interested in then DateTime.Today instead of DateTime.Now is a further simplification. No useless time portion and a bit faster.

Answer (score 40):

If you receive "MMMM" as a response, probably you are getting the month and then converting it to a string of defined format.

```
DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("MMMM")
```

will output "MMMM"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")
```

will output the month name

Answer (score 18):

You can use Culture to get month name for your country like:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-EG");
string FormatDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd., MMM dd yyyy, hh:MM tt", culture);
```

Answer (score 17):

It's

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
```

With 4 `M`s.

Comment: If it's only the month you're interested in then DateTime.Today instead of DateTime.Now is a further simplification. No useless time portion and a bit faster.

Answer (score 14):

```
DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(1981, 8, 9);
Console.WriteLine ("I was born on the {0}. of {1}, {2}.", birthDate.Day, birthDate.ToString("MMMM"), birthDate.Year);

/* The above code will say:
"I was born on the 9. of august, 1981."

"dd" converts to the day (01 thru 31).
"ddd" converts to 3-letter name of day (e.g. mon).
"dddd" converts to full name of day (e.g. monday).
"MMM" converts to 3-letter name of month (e.g. aug).
"MMMM" converts to full name of month (e.g. august).
"yyyy" converts to year.
*/
```

Answer (score 12):

It should be just `DateTime.ToString( "MMMM" )`

You don't need all the extra `M`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
Debug.writeline(Format(Now, "dd MMMM yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CultureInfo from System.Globalization to get that data, based on the current culture that is being used.

```
_ = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month)
```

Or, use InvariantCulture to also get the English name.

```
_ = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need three month letter use "MMM"

Answer (score 0):

Being a popular question, I stumbled upon the very same question even though my requirement was for the newer `DateOnly` type.

Fortunately, the same approach is applicable for the newer data type as well.

```
DateOnly todayDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow); //27-08-2023
string fullMonthName = todayDate.ToString("MMMM");
Console.WriteLine(fullMonthName); //August
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(DateTime = {07/01/2023 12:00:00 AM})

DateTime.ToString("MMMM")  - ( January )
```

Comment: Variants of this answer have already been provided multiple times. When answering older questions, please make sure you provide either a novel solution, or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

Use this for Full name of the month:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string month = $"{date:MMMM}"; // f.g October
```

Use this for abbreviation name of the month:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string month = $"{date:MMM}"; // f.g Oct
```

Use this for full name of the week:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string month = $"{date:dddd}"; // f.g Saturday
```

Use this for abbreviation name of the week:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string month = $"{date:ddd}"; // f.g Sat
```

You can set every custom template with this structure f.g:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string month = $"{date:dd/MMM/yyyy}"; // 12/Oct/2022
string month = $"{date:dd-MM-yyyy}"; // 12-10-2022
string month = $"{date:dd MMMM yyyy}"; // 12 October 2022
string month = $"{date:ddd - - - MMM}"; // Sat - - - Oct
string month = $"{date:ddddd $- yyyy}"; // Saturday $- 2022
string month = $"{date:ddMMyyyy}"; // 12102022
```